# Make screenshot of url

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

When user posts some url, I need to make screenshot of the url content. What .NET library can I use for that?

Comment: You'll need at least a browser or something that can render the HTML. Downloading content is one, but rendering is a different cup of tea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[awesomium](http://awesomium.com/)  is made for this

Answer (score 2):

How about using the Selenium WebDriver? It works from .NET and is quite easy:

```
var browser = new InternetExplorerDriver();
browser.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://example.com");
browser.GetScreenshot().SaveAsFile(filename, ImageFormat.Png);
browser.Quit();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser for this purposes.
You create WebBrowser instance. Then navigate to url and in OnDocumentComplete you can call DrawToBitmap method.
Hope this helps you.

Comment: Which layout engine does this particular class use? Trident?

Comment: yeah :) but there is another implementations this control, for example gecko(http://code.google.com/p/geckofx/) but I am not tested it.

Comment: Isn't **geckofx** an obsolete project?

Comment: I am not sure, I never used it before. I used only WebBrowser class for rendering screenshots... I know that trident is not pretty engine, but it was normal for my purposes. I think this class used installed ie version for navigation. So, you can install ie 9 (or ie 10 in near future) and your screenshots will be more quite :)

Answer (score 1):

Just to mention another option, you could use thumbnail services like:
http://www.thumbalizr.com/
http://webshotspro.com

Thumalizr's sreenshot of this page looks decent and didn't take too long to generate:
[image]